# C++ Socket Recv() and Network Interface going down

Tags: c++, sockets, recv

I have written a client using plain sockets in C to connect to a remote machine to maintain a persistent connection so as to receive push messages. Everything works great. To make it persistent, I have set Keepalive and waiting on recv() function in a loop.

The problem is, when the network interface goes down, the recv() does not return. As I understand from socket documentation that the peer has to disconnect for recv() to return. Network Interface going down is not the same as peer disconnecting.

The need here is that if the network interface goes down, I need to schedule a reconnect so that the channel gets established.

Any thoughts on this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly determine if my client is still connected to the server with C sockets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113539/how-do-i-properly-determine-if-my-client-is-still-connected-to-the-server-with-c)

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever mechanism you wish to force the receive operation to timeout. Depending on the specifics of your use case, you may wish to disconnect if a timeout occurs or you may wish to send something to check the status of the connection.

Whatever protocol you are using on top of TCP should be documented and the documentation should specify how disconnects are detected. You must send to detect a connection loss, so every protocol designed to operate on top of TCP should be designed with this in mind.

Comment: Are keepalives for this purpose to detect "interface downs". I suppose not. Can you please confirm?

Comment: @SenthilAcs They're to detect loss of the connection by any means not detectable otherwise. That includes interface downs on platforms other than Windows.